# Is there a name for integer division in semirings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semiring

For a rig (or semiring) $R$ we can define for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ an element $n * x = \underbrace{x + \dots + x}_n$.

Is there a standard name for the property that $n * x = n * y$ implies $x = y$ for any $n \geq 1$ and $x, y \in R$?

Or does it follow from any standard property?

Comment: You don't need any multiplication here. A (additive) semigroup suffices. I would search with the keywords "power injective semigroup" then, maybe also "torsionfree".

Comment: As a simplification, what you are asking is equivalent to: $n * x \neq 0$ for all $n \ge 1$ and $x \in R \setminus \{0\}$. In other words, you wish for no nonzero element of the additive group $(R, +)$ to have finite order. This is the same as torsion-free, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the name I have encountered this under is "torsionfree ring $R$" meaning that the underlying abelian group is torsionfree: $nx\neq 0$ if $n\in\mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$ and $x\in R\setminus\{0\}$.

Another way to say it is that there are no nonzero elements of $R$ that have finite additive order.

This is equivalent to what you said in the case of *rings* if you group what you wrote as $n(x-y)=0$, and follow the consequences.  But it is only *a consequence* of your definition for semirings.

Comment: This only applies to rings, I think. I am asking about semirings, where one cannot take negatives.

Comment: @daon oh, yeh when I read it the first time I thought you had invoked rngs, and I guess I missed semiring.  Your definition would **imply** the abelian semigroup is torsionfree (in the sense above with Z replaced by N).